# Need help on PAYTM Integration

Tags: payment-gateway

need to integrate PAYTM gateway....he is not providing any documentation and only provides one simple toolkit that contains only one page with some parameters     and didn't mention any validations and request parameters

Answer (score 1):

You need to send a mail to the customer service and they will come back to you with a 3 documents pdf containing the specifications of the API and Android and iOS integration